# How do I prevent a button from shrinking when its content changes without setting a width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have several form buttons positioned in a div using `display: flex`.

[image]

Upon clicking the "Save" button I want to hide the original content of the save button and show a centered spinning icon. However, I do not want the width of the button to change since that causes the page other elements (buttons) around it to shift. Here's what happens with that I have now:

[image]

How do I ensure that the button keeps it's original width and does not shrink? I know I could set a `min-width` on the button, but that would require me to specify a different width for each button this behavior is on since the text could be shorter or longer each time. I have also tried adding various combinations of `flex-shrink: 0` styles to the buttons, but that doesn't seem to work either.

**Code Pen Example**

https://codepen.io/kspearrin/pen/eVNeMX

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="save">
    <span id="savetext"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin hide" id="spinner"></i>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>
    <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("save").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("savetext").classList.add("hide");
  document.getElementById("spinner").classList.remove("hide");
};

document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("savetext").classList.remove("hide");
  document.getElementById("spinner").classList.add("hide");
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to flexboxes: an inline box naturally tries to fit its content if there are no constraints on its size.

Comment: you would need to set a min-width on it or make the save span `visibility:hidden` (then it will keep it's space) and place the spinner absolutely on top of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in comments, it is not related to flexbox: the behavior is normal. A box that is not `display` will fit its content width.

You can use `visibility` and flexbox to set the layout of your spinner.
Here, I just set the upper div to `position:relative`, it does nothing except it becomes the reference for `#spinner` which is `absolute`.
I stretch it to the maximum and center its content with the flexbox :)

```js
document.getElementById("save").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("savetext").classList.add("hide");
  document.getElementById("spinner").classList.remove("hide");
};

document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("savetext").classList.remove("hide");
  document.getElementById("spinner").classList.add("hide");
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#save {
  position: relative;
}

#spinner {
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="save">
    <span id="savetext"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin hide" id="spinner"></i>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>
    <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The updated codepen (font-awesome does not work here): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdOpJd

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` here for the icon so that they dont interface in the flow of button then set `opacity:0` and on click event set `opacity:1` and hide the `text`.

***<sub>Remember to set the `position:relative` of parent</sub>***

And I will also suggest you to add the class to the parent not to every inner elements separately to reduce the code.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.add("hide");
});
document.getElementById("cancel").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.add("hide");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button .fa-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}

button.hide .fa-spinner {
  opacity: 1;
}

button.hide #savetext {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="save">
    <span id="savetext"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin hide" id="spinner"></i>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="cancel">
      <span id="savetext"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin hide" id="spinner"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>
    <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```